# OMDb API multiple results

Tags: php, api, imdb

I'm trying to get a specific movie from IMDB using the IMDO api, It's working great if there is only 1 movie with the title I'm searching for.

But if there are multiple movies, I one get the first, sorted by year I'm assuming.

How can I get all of the movies with the title?

I doing it in PHP.

```
<?php
  //Get movie data
  if($_GET['title']){
    $titleInput = "t=" . str_replace(' ', '+', $_GET['title']);
    $jsonUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?" . $titleInput;
  }else if($_GET['imdbid']){
    $titleInput = "i=" . str_replace(' ', '+', $_GET['imdbid']);
    $jsonUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?" . $titleInput; 
  }
  $jsonRaw = file_get_contents($jsonUrl);    
  $movieArray = json_decode($jsonRaw, true);
?>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question?

Comment: I got it working yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get multiple results by title use the `s=title` instead of the `t=title` parameter as documented [here](http://www.omdbapi.com/).

As far as I understood it the *"By Search"* parameter can return multiple results whereas the *"By ID or Title"* parameter will return a single one.